# how to check which checkbox was checked first

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a fieldset of checkboxes and I want to know which checkbox was checked first and so on. I tried to create an array that pushes the value when the user checked the input but it didn't work.

```html
<label for="B" class="mainLabel mainTop" id="labelB">B</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="mainForm[]" id="B" value="B" onClick="return KeepCount()">

<label for="E" class="mainLabel mainTop" id="labelE">E</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="mainForm[]" id="E" value="E" onClick="return KeepCount()">

<label for="LM" class="mainLabel mainTop" id="labelLM">LM</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="mainForm[]" value="LM" id="LM" onClick="return KeepCount()">

<label for="UM" class="mainLabel mainTop" id="labelUM">UM</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="mainForm[]" value="UM" id="UM" onClick="return KeepCount()">

<label for="SL" class="mainLabel mainTop" id="labelSL">SL</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="mainForm[]" value="SL" id="SL" onClick="return KeepCount()">
```

Comment: The array you've described is the way to go, please show the attempt.

Comment: Please add the code you attempted to write which didn't work. Remember, we're here to help you debug code, not to write it for you

Comment: add function keepcount in snippet

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution using Jquery.

I had to delete the `keepCount()` cause its not included in your code

```js
var click = false;
var arr = [];
$('.mainLabel+input').each(function() {
  $(this).change(function() {
    if (!click) {
      console.log("First= " + $(this).val());
      click = true;
    } else {
      console.log("and so on= " + $(this).val());
    }
    arr.push($(this));
    console.log("Array= " + arr);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="B" class="mainLabel mainTop" id="labelB">B</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="mainForm[]" id="B" value="B">

<label for="E" class="mainLabel mainTop" id="labelE">E</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="mainForm[]" id="E" value="E">

<label for="LM" class="mainLabel mainTop" id="labelLM">LM</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="mainForm[]" value="LM" id="LM">

<label for="UM" class="mainLabel mainTop" id="labelUM">UM</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="mainForm[]" value="UM" id="UM">

<label for="SL" class="mainLabel mainTop" id="labelSL">SL</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="mainForm[]" value="SL" id="SL">
```

Comment: @Teemu sorry but i dont really know what is "and so on". I foucs in the first one clicked

Comment: @T.sagiv Did my answer help you, or did you ran into trouble?